# declare in oracle and select error

Tags: oracle

i am trying to run the following code in sql developer.

```
declare ptbl varchar2(50) := 'TRM_SPAN_MST' ;
begin
select ptbl from dual ; 
end
```

but showing following error

```
    Error starting at line 8 in command:
    declare ptbl varchar2(50) := 'TRM_SPAN_MST' ;
        begin
        select ptbl from dual ; 
        end
    Error report:
    ORA-06550: line 4, column 7:
    PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

       ; <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
    The symbol ";" was substituted for "end-of-file" to continue.
    06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
    *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
    *Action:
```

Comment: What you are trying to do? In anonymous block you should use `SELECT ... INTO`. If you want to print variable value, then use `dbms_output.put_line(ptbl);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error, you need **;** after last **end**.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to avoid getting an error:

```
DECLARE 
    ptbl varchar2(50);
BEGIN
    SELECT 'TRM_SPAN_MST' into ptbl FROM DUAL ; 
END;
```